# Navbar slider not transparent over images

Tags: html, css, reactjs, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm building a website at the moment with React.js, and have a problem with the nav bar. I have a slider, and I want the navbar to be above a slider. However, my nav is pushing down the slider. The navbar should be above the slider images, with transparency, so I can see the navbar and the image behind it.

Here is the my codes, to make the elements look as I want them to lookwhat should I change or add?

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import About from './components/About';

import Products from './components/Products';
import ProductDetail from './components/ProductDetail';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Gallery from './components/Gallery';
import Catalog from './components/Catalog';
import Slider from './components/Slider';
import CustomNavbar from './components/CustomNavbar';


function App() {
    const products = [ ];
  
  return (
    <Router>
    <div>

      <CustomNavbar />
      
    <div>
      
       
          
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>} />
            <Route path="/products/*" element={<Products products={products} />}/>
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetail products={products} />} />
            <Route path="/products/binek" element={<Products products={products} />}/>
            <Route path="/products/agirvasita" element={<Products products={products} />}/>
            <Route path='/gallery' element={<Gallery />}/>
            <Route path='/catalog' element={<Catalog/>}/>
            <Route path="/map" component={Map} />
          </Routes>
                
          
        </div>
              
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}


function HomePage({ about, productType }) {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
      <Slider images={['home1.jpg', 'home2.jpg', 'home3.jpg', 'home4.jpg', 'home5.jpg']} />
      <CustomNavbar style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)', 
        padding: '10px',
        zIndex: '1',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
      }} />
      </div>
   
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

**CustomNavbar.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink, useNavigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar as BootstrapNavbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "../App.css";

function CustomNavbar() {
  const [isProductDropdownOpen, setProductDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isMediaDropdownOpen, setMediaDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const [logoStyles, setLogoStyles] = useState({
    width: '10%',
    height: 'auto',
    marginLeft: '5%',
    marginTop: '1%',
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleProductDropdownOpen = () => {
    setProductDropdownOpen(true);
  };

  const handleProductDropdownClose = () => {
    setProductDropdownOpen(false);
  };

  const handleProductClick = () => {
    navigate('/products');
  };

  const handleBinekClick = () => {
    navigate('/products/binek');
  };

  const handleAgirVasitaClick = () => {
    navigate('/products/agirvasita');
  };

  const handleMediaDropdownOpen = () => {
    setMediaDropdownOpen(true);
  };

  const handleMediaDropdownClose = () => {
    setMediaDropdownOpen(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        setLogoStyles({
          width: '25%',
          height: 'auto',
          marginLeft: 'auto',
          marginRight: 'auto',
          marginTop: '1%',
        });
      } else {
        setLogoStyles({
          width: '10%',
          height: 'auto',
          marginLeft: '5%',
          marginTop: '1%',
        });
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return (
     <BootstrapNavbar
      bg="light"
      expand="lg"
      
      
    >
      <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
        <BootstrapNavbar.Brand style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <img
            src="polat-logo-01.png"
            className="d-block"
            style={logoStyles}
            alt="Logo"
          />
        </BootstrapNavbar.Brand>
      </Link>

      <BootstrapNavbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" id="custom-toggle" />

      <BootstrapNavbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
        <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">
            ANASAYFA
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/about" className="nav-link">
            KURUMSAL
          </NavLink>

        
          <NavDropdown
          title="ÜRÜNLER"
          id="product-dropdown"
          show={isProductDropdownOpen}
          onMouseOver={handleProductDropdownOpen}
          onMouseLeave={handleProductDropdownClose}
         
        >
        <NavLink
            to="/products/"
            className={`dropdown-item ${isProductDropdownOpen ? 'show' : ''}`}
          >
            TÜM ÜRÜNLER
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/products/binek"
            className={`dropdown-item ${isProductDropdownOpen ? 'show' : ''}`}
          >
            BİNEK
          </NavLink>
        
          <NavLink
            to="/products/agirvasita"
            className={`dropdown-item ${isProductDropdownOpen ? 'show' : ''}`}
          >
            AĞIR VASITA
          </NavLink>
        </NavDropdown>

          <NavDropdown
            title="MEDYA"
            id="media-dropdown"
            show={isMediaDropdownOpen}
            onMouseOver={handleMediaDropdownOpen}
            onMouseLeave={handleMediaDropdownClose}
          >
            {/*<NavLink to="/news" className="dropdown-item">
              HABERLER & DUYURULAR
             </NavLink>*/}
            <NavLink to="/catalog" className="dropdown-item">
              KATALOG
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/gallery" className="dropdown-item">
              ÜRETİM GALERİSİ
            </NavLink>
          </NavDropdown>

          <NavLink to="/contact" className="nav-link">
            İLETİŞİM
          </NavLink>
        </Nav>
      </BootstrapNavbar.Collapse>

      <Outlet />
    </BootstrapNavbar>
  );
}

export default CustomNavbar;
```

**Slider.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Slider = ({ images }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleNext = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % images.length);
  };

  const handlePrev = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex - 1 + images.length) % images.length);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '100%', height: '100vh', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <img
          key={index}
          src={image}
          alt={`Slider Image ${index + 1}`}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            position: index === currentIndex ? 'relative' : 'absolute',
            opacity: index === currentIndex ? 1 : 0,
            transition: 'opacity 0.5s ease-in-out',
          }}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={handlePrev} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '10px', zIndex: 1 }}>
        Previous
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleNext} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '50%', right: '10px', zIndex: 1 }}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```